# Combining duplications for backend blocks in haproxy.cfg

Tags: haproxy

I have this HAProxy config and as you can see I have many duplicated stuff in `backend`s. Is there a way of getting rid of duplications such as `stats`?

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    daemon
    maxconn 2000

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    acl url_a path_reg ^\/a$|\/a\/
    use_backend webservers_a if url_a
    acl url_b path_reg ^\/b$|\/b\/
    use_backend webservers_b if url_b
    default_backend webservers_main

backend webservers_main
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server web1 192.168.50.21:80 maxconn 32 check

backend webservers_a
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server web2 192.168.50.22:80 maxconn 32 check

backend webservers_b
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats auth admin:admin
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    server web3 192.168.50.23:80 maxconn 32 check
```

Comment: You could insert another `frontend` bound to an private IP and move the `stats` directives there.

Comment: I've just added `frontend stats ......` and getting `'stats' ignored because frontend 'stats' has no backend capability.` error. Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add something like the following to your config:

```
listen stats
    bind ${PRIVATE_IP}:${PORT}
    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats auth admin:admin
```

- I'm assuming the following points:
- You don't want to expose your `stats` to the public. If this is not the case, just move your stats into your existing `frontend` directive.
- Substitute `${PRIVATE_IP}` with an private IP which is available on your machine (or set up one for this), and `${PORT}` with an unused port, for example `8080`.
- Caveat: If you use a different port than `80` in your stats directive, you would have to call your `stats` page by specifying the port in the `url`. To prevent and circumvent that:

  - Bind your `frontend` to `${PUBLIC_IP}:80`, and your `listen stats` section to `${PRIVATE_IP}:80`.